# SQL date formats on INSERT statement - can be affected by server updates?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2003

We have a stored procedure that currently runs to insert data into a table

The sp gets a date value from a text file and assigns it to a `VARCHAR(10)` variable. The variable value is then inserted into a table column that is datetime

This sp has worked fine for some time

The client noticed today that the dates are being inserted incorrectly - so if the incoming file has '07/02/2014' (7th Feb), the sp is inserting it as 2nd July

Normally it would insert 2014-02-07, but is now inserting 2014-07-02

Our server recently had some Windows Server 2003 updates applied - could any of these affect the way SQL Server is converting the date?

I'm not listing the exact KB numbers applied, I would just like to know in general if the updates can affect the way SQL affects the treating of the insert

When I run

```
sp_helplanguage @@language
```

the dateformat is returned as "dmy"

Comment: It's a good reason to stick to unambiguous formats, such as `20140207`, if at all possible.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I completely agree. Sadly we have no control over the file/dsata coming in from the client but I am certainly going to look at a middle step to convert all date values to be unambiguous

Comment: What was the dateformat returned by the server prior to the windows update?

Comment: @abhi - I am unable to tell that as we only became aware of the problem post update